# What is the WITH statement doing in this example? I'm trying to randomly generate data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, with-statement

```
INSERT INTO files (fileUID, filename)
WITH fileUIDS(fileUID) AS
( VALUES(1) UNION ALL
  SELECT fileUID+1 FROM fileUIDS WHERE fileUID < 1000 )
SELECT fileUID,
       TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 10000000000 )), 'abcdefgHij', '1234567890' )
FROM fileUIDS;
```

Comment: BTW, unrelated to your question about WITH, in general, rand() will return the same value for an entire SQL statement, now matter how many rows are returned. If you want different values, then: loop and call rand() on each iteration, call rand with a seed that changes per row (not very random) or use NEWID or NEW_ID, whichever it is. Search stackoverflow for examples.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The WITH syntax is the same as using either a local temp table or inline view.  To my knowledge, it's only supported in SQL Server (2005+, called Common Table Expressions) and Oracle (9i+, called Subquery Factoring).  The intended use is for creating a basic view that is used (ie: joined to) multiple times in a single query.

Here's a typical example:

```
WITH example AS (
     SELECT q.question_id,
            t.tag_name
       FROM QUESTIONS q
       JOIN QUESTION_TAG_XREF qtf ON qtf.question_id = t.question_id
       JOIN TAGS t ON t.tag_id = qtf.tag_id)
SELECT t.title,
       e1.tag_name
  FROM QUESTIONS t
  JOIN example e1 ON e1.question_id = t.question_id
```

...which will return identical results if you use:

```
SELECT t.title,
       e1.tag_name
  FROM QUESTIONS t
  JOIN (SELECT q.question_id,
               t.tag_name
          FROM QUESTIONS q
          JOIN QUESTION_TAG_XREF qtf ON qtf.question_id = t.question_id
          JOIN TAGS t ON t.tag_id = qtf.tag_id) e1 ON e1.question_id = t.question_id
```

The example you provided:

```
WITH fileUIDS(fileUID) AS ( 
     VALUES(1) 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT t.fileUID+1 
       FROM fileUIDS t
      WHERE t.fileUID < 1000 )
INSERT INTO files 
    (fileUID, filename)
SELECT f.fileUID,
       TRANSLATE ( CHAR(BIGINT(RAND() * 10000000000 )), 'abcdefgHij', '1234567890' )
  FROM fileUIDS f;
```

...is a recursive one.  It's starting at 1, generating 999 fileuids in total (it would be 1,000 if it had started at 0).

Comment: DB2 supports WITH. See page 510 of ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/ps/products/db2/info/vr82/pdf/en_US/db2s1e81.pdf. Oracle does not support the recursive form of WITH until 11gR2. (They have had CONNECT BY to support recursion for quite awhile.)

Comment: @Shannon: Thx, didn't know about DB2.  I prefer the CONNECT BY syntax - seeing it in CTEs looks like such a hack.

Answer (score 4):

```
WITH x AS (...)
```

This will take the output of the `...` and treat it as a table named `x`, temporarily.

```
WITH x AS (...)
SELECT * FROM x
```

This statement will essentially give you the exact same thing as the `...` outputs but it will instead be referenced as the table `x`

Answer (score 0):

The WITH word is used to create a Common Table Expression (CTE).  In this case, it's creating an inline table that the "select fileUID, ..." part is pulling data from.

Answer (score 0):

It is creating CTE (Common Table Expression).  This is a basically a table that you don't have to create, drop, or declare in anyway.  It will be automatically deleted after the batch has ran.

Check out https://web.archive.org/web/20210927200924/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml for more info.